# What (electrical) property does $\alpha$ represent with units of $\textrm{K}^{-1}$?

Tags: electricity, electrical-resistance

What property does $\alpha$ represent  in the following passage?

> . . . A block (made of material of $ρ_o = 0.5 \, Ω·m$ and $α=0.004\,\textrm{K}^{-1}$) with dimensions ℓ = 8 cm, w = 3 cm, and h = 6 cm is maintained (by external means) at room temperature (20 $ ^{\circ}$C) . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably it is the linear [temperature coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperature_coefficient) of resistivity (or of resistance as they come down to the same thing).